# cocos2d scene in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to show a cocos2D-iPhone scene from within a UIViewController. Cocos2d should use the UIViewController's view as the rendering area. How could this be done?

(Targeting iOS 4.2)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is in the tests in the cocos2d source file.

Look at 'attachDemo' under the 'tests' folder.

It demonstrates adding and removing a cocos2d view.

It seems to create an EAGLView and add that as a subview of the UIView, then set up the director and cocos2d as normal within that glview.

mainView is a UIView.

```
    EAGLView *glview = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250,350)];
    [mainView addSubview:glview];

    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [director setOpenGLView:glview];

    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    id node = [LayerExample node];
    [scene addChild: node];

    [director runWithScene:scene];
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: I had tried this approach, but all I could get was a black screen.. no idea why it wasn't showing the scene...

Comment: it seems that it worked all the time.. just the coordinates seem to be mixed up and translated or something

Comment: sorry, only just got back to this. I'm guessing that (0,0) is no longer relative to the corner of the screen? You'll probably have to offset whatever the frame of your cocos2d view is.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Cocos2D 2.x and XCode 4.3 with storyboard, I recommend this blog post:
http://www.tinytimgames.com/2012/02/07/cocos2d-and-storyboards/

Because some functions are deprecated since Cocos2D 1.x.

Totally worked :)